# Can't get default check on RadioButtonFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a razor `RadioButtonFor` that I am trying to check by default but nothing works. Here is my Code:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.selected, new {@checked=true});
```

Where `selected` is a boolean. And the Html Generated:

```
<input name="selected" id="selected" type="radio" 
 value="{ Name = groupRadio, checked = True }">
```

I've also tried

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.selected, 0, new {@checked=true});
```

which didn't work either. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It's `RadioButtonFor()` (notice the `For`) because it's calculating the current state of the radio button based on the value of `m.selected`. If you want the set the value yourself, use `Html.RadioButton()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `selected` is `bool`, then your radio buttons need to be

```
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.selected, true, new { id = "" });
    <span>Yes</span>
</label>
<label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.selected, false, new { id = "" });
    <span>No</span>
</label>
```

Note the 2nd parameter generates the `value` attribute to bind to your `bool` property.

Then if the value of `selected` is `true`, the first will be selected, otherwise the 2nd will be

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use `Html.IdFor + "Yes"`, etc., for the `id` values, rather than empty strings?

Comment: @TiesonT., The method generates duplicate `id` attributes so I just remove them. But yes, that would be an alternative, if you also modified the `id` in `RadioButtonFor()` and the `for` attribute in the `Html.LabelFor()`